# Python Progam to read SDF (chemistry) file

Tags: python, chemistry

I want to read [sdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#SDF) file (containing many molecules) and return the weighted adjacency matrix of the molecule. Atoms should be treated as vertices and bond as edges. If *i* and *j* vertex are connected by single, double, or triple bond then corresponding entries in the adjacency matrix should be 1,2, and 3 respectively. I need to further obtain a *distance vector* for each vertex which list the number of vertices at different distance.

Are there any python package available to do this?

Comment: Google, first result seems to be exactly that! https://github.com/mbarriault/PySDF

Comment: Were you aware of this before or found now just by googling? I also searched but could not find. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Pybel](http://openbabel.org/docs/2.3.1/UseTheLibrary/Python_Pybel.html) for reading and manipulating SDF files in Python. To get the bonding information, you will probably need to also use the more full-featured but less pythonic [openbabel module](http://openbabel.org/docs/2.3.1/UseTheLibrary/PythonDoc.html), which can be used in concert with Pybel (as pybel.ob).

To start with, you would write something like this:

```
import pybel

for mol in pybel.readfile('sdf', 'many_molecules.sdf'):
  for atom in mol:
    coords = atom.coords
    for neighbor in pybel.ob.OBAtomAtomIter(atom.OBAtom):
      neighbor_coords = pybel.atom(neighbor).coords
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the most commonly used package [rdkit](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html) to process the SDF chemical file? It is really fast and convenient.

```
suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier('xxx.sdf') # name the path of the SDF file 
for mol in supply:
    print(mol.GetNumAtoms()) # give the number of atoms in each molecule
    ......                   # do whatever kind of operations you want
```

Answer (score 0):

See

http://code.google.com/p/cinfony/

However for your exact problem you will need to consult the documentation.

Comment: Is cinfony available for python 3.7?